# Backbone.js and Require.js tool r.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, r.js

So in my TODO applications i used Backbone and require.js. All is cool. I separated all models, views, collections to single files and use require.js to load them. After i tried to join all files to one using console require.js optimizer r.js. As i result i get one file with all my libs and classes. But when i tryed to run i met error that Backbone undefined. I checked the file and see that r.js generated next thing:
1. First it added backbone sources to app-built.js file and after placed next string

```
define("lib/backbone", function(){});
```

So as result i have Backbone variable in the window but in my modules i use it in require.js way 
`define('models/todo',['jquery','underscore','lib/backbone'],function ($, _, Backbone) {`

No as global and as result in my modules Backbone local variable is undefined.
And the same problem with underscore.js. R.js imported it in the same way.

So question. How to avoid this problem with othew libs in future or how to fix this now? SOme technics?

Comment: This part is unclear to me: "No as global". Can you rephrase or expand on this? Perhaps a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to use a shim since Backbone according to the RequireJS expects Backbone to be in the base url directory. In your case, it appears to be in the /lib instead. [Config Shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim). Depending on the RequireJS version that you're using, you just have to make sure as well that the library that you're using is AMD compatible.

In your requireJS configuration:

```
shim: {
  backbone: {
    deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
    attach: "Backbone"
  },
  underscore: {
    attach: "_"
  }
}
```